# aggregation version of $, positional operator that selects the first element of an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

```
{ "_id" : 1, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 70, 87, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 90, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 85, 100, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 79, 85, 80 ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 88, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 95, 90, 96 ] }
```

```
db.students.find( { semester: 1, grades: { $gte: 85 } },
                  { "grades.$": 1 } )
```

```
{ "_id" : 1, "grades" : [ 87 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "grades" : [ 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "grades" : [ 85 ] }
```

By adding the `{ "grades.$": 1 } )` bit in the find query, the result returns the first element of the grades array of the matching documents.

Is there something equivalent for the `$match` stage with a `$elemMatch` of an aggregation pipeline?

Comment: Use `$filter` in projection. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TUBHWS2osQk)

Comment: I am aware of $filter, which is redundant work. I am trying to replace that.

Comment: Why do you think `$filter` is redundant? It is even mentioned in the documentation: *"See the aggregation operator `$filter` to return an array with only those elements that match the specified condition."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask the wrong question. The `find()` operator is

```
db.collection.find(query, projection, options)
```

With

```
db.students.find( 
   { semester: 1, grades: { $gte: 85 } },
   { "grades.$": 1 } 
)
```

the positional operator refers to *projection*, not the match *condition*. Operator `$elemMatch` does not exist for aggregation pipelines.

With an aggregation pipeline the equivalent would be

```
db.students.aggregate([
   { $match: { semester: 1, grades: { $gte: 85 } } },
   {
      $project: {
         grades: [{
            $arrayElemAt: [
               {
                  $filter: {
                     input: "$grades",
                     cond: { $gte: ["$$this", 85] }
                  }
               },
               0
            ]
         }]
      }
   }
])
```

or a bit shorter:

```
db.students.aggregate([
   { $match: { semester: 1, grades: { $gte: 85 } } },
   {
      $project: {
         grades: [{
            $first: {
               $filter: {
                  input: "$grades",
                  cond: { $gte: ["$$this", 85] }
               }
            }
         }]
      }
   }
])
```

[Monog Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XX89TDJaa_h)